# GPIO audio in vs using analog microphone - closed as duplicate

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, duplicates

There are two questions that I think are quite different if you read them whole, not just the title.

- [Analog Microphone with Raspberry PI [duplicate]](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/69615/5844)
- [Can I get audio input through the GPIO](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/4341/5844)

I don't think these are duplicate at all. The second question is a generic inquiry about whether there is a pin for audio on Raspberry, whereas in the first one, the OP already has a specific microphone and needed help setting it up.

Because their question was shutdown as duplicate, they had to look for help elsewhere. The older "duplicate" question does not say anything about that microphone or **any** microphone for that matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fair enough, that is indeed not an useful duplicate. I have reopened the question... I hope you had an answer in mind, feel free to post it.